# Problem with request using Axios on react native 0.57

Tags: android, react-native, xmlhttprequest, apk, axios

I have a complex issue.
I'm using axios for my requests to Django server. When i use debug apk there is no problem, but when i sign and get release apk, some requests pend in axios block.
I can't see the log of release apk, therefore i can't understand what is the problem. Could you please help me?
In addition cors errors are handled from server side.

Comment: My be it is because of HTTPS